# This jQuery selector is very slow. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am creating a simple jQuery object by passing in some HTML string. In IE7 though, the alert tells me it takes around 125ms.

```
var timeStart = new Date();
var allTabs = jQuery(tmbJsContent);

var timeEnd = new Date();
alert(timeEnd-timeStart);
```

tmbJsContent contains html for 10 divs that contains tables inside. I understand its a little long but since no DOM is being manipulated, and just one jQuery object is being created. What could take so long? How can I make this faster?

Thanks

Comment: And you didn't find it necessary to post the value of the `tmbJsContent` variable?

Comment: @Darin - How diplomatic of you... :)

Comment: Why are you using IE7? :P Its the bastard browser everyone skips over...

Comment: Tell users to stop using IE7 is the only way to make your script go faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a container element and update its `innerHTML` contents

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = tmbJsContent;
```

Should take about a millisecond :)

Comment: how come? this is standard javascript and should work everywhere, event in IE6. `document.createElement` is a standard DOM method and `innerHTML` was *invented* by IE.

Comment: Becaise IE6 does not support the manipulation of innerHTML ;( Don't get me wrong here my friend, your answer is perfect, the browser is the one with the imperfections.

Comment: Are you sure your'e not talking about IE4? `innerHTML` (and `outerHTML`) were invented by Microsoft and have been present since Internet Explorer 5.

Comment: Hey Andris, I actually just verified. The innerHTML is acceptable in IE6 as long as you are not using it on a table. Disregard my comment :P  But try it out if you want to see the effects, just try to manipulate innerHtml of a table cell or something.  Kind of odd it doesnt work!

Comment: yeah, I can agree with that, managing tables in IE6 is a real pain in the a** either with or without `innerHMTL` :)

Answer (score 1):

To truly answer this we need to see the value of *tmbJsContent*...

**In the meantime**, if your selector is slow try restricting the "search area" for the selector by passing-in the container (as context).

**EXAMPLE:**

```
var context = jQuery('#SomeContainer');
var target = jQuery('MySelector', context);
```

This restricts the selector-search to the container being passed-in.